# Cannot read property 'retryAttempts' of undefined on nestjs typeorm

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

When I run the nestjs application, I get the error **"Cannot read property 'retryAttempts' of undefined."** on @nestjs/typeorm

The module version is **@nestjs/typeorm ^7.1.5**, **typeorm ^0.2.34**

How do I fix it?

Error Message

```
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmConfigModule dependencies initialized +50ms
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [InstanceLoader] PostModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [InstanceLoader] UserModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 5632   - 2021. 09. 02. 오후 9:55:42   [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property 'retryAttempts' of undefined +4ms
TypeError: Cannot read property 'retryAttempts' of undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\project\fashion-is-my-life-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:173:59)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\project\fashion-is-my-life-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:20:71
    at __awaiter (C:\project\fashion-is-my-life-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:16:12)
    at Function.createConnectionFactory (C:\project\fashion-is-my-life-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:142:16)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\project\fashion-is-my-life-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:65:35)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\project\fashion-is-my-life-backend\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm-core.module.js:20:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

It is an error that occurs in a module, so I am not sure where exactly it is coming from.

Comment: Can you give some code examples, where this error was catched?

Comment: I'm editing the post because it's too long to write in a comment. Please check the edited post again

Comment: Hmm, try delete node_modules directory and `npm i`

Comment: I already tried it but still got an error

Comment: @yangseungbin, Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the config data you sent is empty or invalid. Regardless of the way you are using it, this error is thrown if invalid data is provided in arguments.
For example:
If `esModuleInterop: false` in `ts.config` and you imported the config file as `import ormConfig from 'src/config/ormConfig'` will be undefined. 
Rather import the file as `import * as ormConfig from 'src/config/ormConfig'`.